# JSON: show div if error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The JSON.parse are working properly, it show the value i need, but i wanted to show the div once i get an error.

```
 var stock= $.parseJSON(stock); //This is Yii
```

Once i select a product (from my dropdown) that has remaining stock, it display **"string"** (i use **typeof** in stock to get the data type).

```
 console.log(typeof(stock)); // display "string"
```

but once i select a product that has no remaining stock, it does not display a value but instead an error on **console**.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

I tried to put a condition,

```
 //-------------------------------------
  if(typeof(stock) != 'string'){
      $('#stock-'+id+'-alert').show();
  }
  else{
       $('#stock-'+id+'-alert').hide();
  }


 //-------------------------------------
  if(stock == '' || stock == 'undefined' || stock == 0 )
    {
           $('#stock-'+id+'-alert').show();
    }
else{
           $('#stock-'+id+'-alert').hide();
```

it display a value on **console** if products has remaining stocks.

but if the product has no stock it display an error to the console and doesn't show the division.

This is the **DIV** i wanted to show once i get an Invalid JSON or an error.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="stock-<?=$i?>-alert" role="alert" style=" width:50%; margin:auto; margin-bottom:10px; font-size: 16px;">This Product has no Stocks!</div>
```

Comment: `stock == 'undefined'` cannot work, you probably mean `typeof(stock) === "undefined"`

Comment: What are the possible values you can receive for stock? I would assume what ever you query should give you always a number, i.e: `0` or higher. Why are you checking for the type? Either way, map your stock value to a number before using it in your code logic, that way the rest of your code only has to worry about `if(stock > 0)...` etc...

Comment: @Nope i only tried using typeof because i wanted to check the value if undefined, i saw them using it so i try to apply it on my system. but in the first place there are no typeof, the value of stock is a number but i also try to put a condition( you can see them from above, the second condition).

Comment: @zxKazumaxz While the suggested `try..catch` in the answer below does look like it will solve your issue I would be more interested in why invalid JSON would be passed to you to begin with and if I understand your code correctly why are you trying to **hide** a possible error. In general I don't error handle unexpected conditions and let the system blow up in those cases. If a JSON value is expected then it is what has to be passed. If you are being passed invalid JSON you are **assuming** there is no stock, though it could mean anything. Invalid JSON === let the code blow up IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a try / catch block:

```
try {
  var stock= $.parseJSON(stock);
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
 //show div
}
```

Comment: i forgot to add on my code above that i already tried `try .. catch`

Comment: im sorry i forgot put the variable stocks inside try block. but now its working haha Yea Rock! Thank you.